# How to use Modernizr in head to conditionally load JS - TypeError produced

Tags: modernizr

After loading Modernizr in my page's head, I'm trying to test for a feature - if it fails it need to load some JavaScript. However, I'm getting the following console error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Modernizr.load([{
        test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
        nope : '/path/to/polyfill.js'
    }
])')
```

My `<head>` section looks like:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="path/to/modernizr.js"></script>

    <script>
    Modernizr.load([{
        test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
        nope : '/path/to/polyfill.js'
    }
    ]);
    </script>
</head>
```

How do I correctly conditionally load in the head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't have `Modernizr.load` [checked off](http://modernizr.com/download/#-load) in your build of modernizr. That being said, Modernizr.load has been removed from the pre-release version of modernizr, becuase it was just a thin wrapper around [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/). You can rebuild your build with `.load` included, but I would highly suggest skipping that and just loading yepnope instead.

Comment: I was actually using the development version which currently has Modernizr.load included by default. However I went for yepnope separately and that seemed to fix the issue.